# TYPO3 determine page type of menu item and wrap div with custom class around it

Tags: typo3, typoscript

My goal is to apply different navigation logic to different page types. For example `shortcut` type will be container (drop down list in FE, shortcut itself is dummy link), `standard` type - page with content that you can navigate to. So, when in FE navigation user selects page:

```
drop-down list appears
if (type of page in list == standard)
    can navigate to page in list;
else if (type of page in list == shortcut)
   GO TO drop-down list appears
```

I know that you can do something like this:

```
lib {
    main-nav = HMENU
    main-nav {
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1
            NO = 1
            NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            NO.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
            NO.stdWrap.cObject {
                key.field = doktype
                default = TEXT
                default {
                    field = title
                }
                # standard page type
                1 = TEXT
                1 {
                    field = title
                    wrap = <div>|</div>
                }....
```

As a result you get page title wrapped with `div` if page type is `standard`.

But what do i need to do to wrap whole menu item rather then just wrapping title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just about putting the div around the whole submenu, I guess what you already got should be applied to wrapItemAndSub instead

```
lib {
    main-nav = HMENU
    main-nav {
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1
            NO = 1
            NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject = CASE
            NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject {
                key.field = doktype
                default = TEXT
                default {
                    value = <li>|</li>
                }
                # standard page type
                1 = TEXT
                1 {
                    value = <li><div>|</div></li>
                }....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to combine HTML, CSS and javascript.

In the typoscript you prepare the HTML with different markup depending on page type. Then your javascript has to handle the click event in case of a shortcut page where a click should open a drop down instead of going to that page. (add eventhandler)

So you need to give javascript something to identify the shortcut pages.
With the CASE object you mentioned you can build the apropiate HTML with all neccessary information (you might use data- attributes).

For a more detailed help you need to be more specific what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for fuzzy question, i edited it to be more clear. Can you please provide an example of using data attributes you mentioned to wrap, for example, custom div around menu item?